# Having trouble writing a property wrapper for Swift Strings

Tags: swift, swift-property-wrapper

Trying to write a property wrapper like so:

```swift
@propertyWrapper struct LessThanSixteen<String> {
    var value: String
    
    var wrappedValue: String {
        get { value }
//        set { value = }
    }
    
    init(wrappedValue: String) {
        var x = wrappedValue
        self.value = (wrappedValue.count < 16) ? wrappedValue : wrappedValue.dropLast(wrappedValue.count - 16)
    }
}
```

The line `self.value = (wrappedValue.count < 16) ? wrappedValue : wrappedValue.dropLast(wrappedValue.count - 16)` is throwing 2 errors.  "Value of type 'String' has no member 'count'" and "Value of type 'String' has no member 'dropLast'".  I don't understand why the compiler says that.

if I write this code outside of a `@propertyWrapper` struct:

```
let someString = "this string is more than 16 characters long"
let someSubstring = String(someString.dropLast(someString.count - 16))
```

I get no such compiler errors.  I don't understand why I can't do that code inside the property wrapper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`struct LessThanSixteen<String>` declares a *generic type*, with a generic type parameter named "String", in the same way that [`Array<Element>`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array) is a generic type with a type parameter named `Element`.

Therefore, the word `String` inside the property wrapper refers to the generic type parameter, not the Swift built-in `String` type (and is totally unrelated to it).

"What types of properties can a property wrapper be applied on" is not determined by generic type parameters. It is determined by the type of `wrappedValue`. Of course, if the type of `wrappedValue` is a generic type parameter, then the property wrapper can be applied to properties with types that the type parameter can be.

If you want a property wrapper that only works on `String`s, just make `wrappedValue` a `String`.

```
@propertyWrapper struct LessThanSixteen {
    private var value: String
    
    var wrappedValue: String {
        get { value }
        set {
            value = String(newValue.prefix(16))
        }
    }
    
    init(wrappedValue: String) {
        var x = wrappedValue
        self.value = String(wrappedValue.prefix(16))
    }
}
```

Comment: That makes sense.  I did try something like `@propertyWrapper struct LessThanSixteen<Value: StringProtocol>{ ...` first, but I was also having issues doing "stringy" type things with `Value`.  This is a "challenge" in some online training I was going through.  The session was on generics and the instructor showed us a propertyWrapper that used generics, so I guess in my head I was just assuming I too needed to use Generics to solve the challenge.  However, your solutions works just fine.  Thanks!